# Warning : Trigger created with compilation errors

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I wrote this trigger to update the date of avaibility of a video when a broadcast is added

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_avaibility
AFTER INSERT ON CAST FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    lastCast DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(diffusionDate) 
      INTO lastCast 
      FROM CAST 
     WHERE idVideo = :NEW.idVideo;

    UPDATE VIDEO 
       SET diffusionDate = (lastCast + 14 day) 
     WHERE idVideo = :NEW.idVideo;
END;
/
```

However I have the following warning when I run it :

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

I have the following errors :

```
LINE/COL   ERROR
---------- -------------------------------------
5/2        SQL Statement ignored
5/61       ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Can someone help me and tell me what i am doing wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: `show errors;` please

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know this command ! My errors are SQL Statement ignored & missing right parenthesis

Comment: `cast` is a function name - it's a really bad idea to name objects using keywords or reserved words. You are also going to get mutating table errors. What are you really trying to do, and why? A trigger is probably not the right solution.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  In some versions, `cast` is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

the first error is

```
lastCast + 14 day
```

if lastCast is date. you should change to

```
lastCast + 14
```

or to

```
lastCast + interval '14' day
```

Comment: Now i have the error "diffusionDate: invalid identifier"

Comment: It means in table `VIDEO` column `diffusionDate` not exists